# tkinter y sockets en python

Tags: python, tkinter, socket

tengo un problema a la hora de ejecutar una app de python con tkinter , la app se conecta a un servidor que funciona bien el problema viene varios segundos después de realizar la conexión , resulta que la aplicación no responde y se queda colgada.

```
from tkinter import *
import socket
import sys
import os



host = 'localhost'
port = 9000


window = Tk()
window.geometry('500x400')

#m = Entry(window,width=10)
#m.grid(column=6, row=7)
#msg = str.encode(m.get())
#type(msg)
#type(msg)

def conex():
  os.system('telnet localhost 9000')
btn = Button(window, text="dale", command=conex)
btn.grid(column=5, row=4)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: lo ideal es que no uses os.system explicado por abulafia, si haces la importacion de la libreria socket, porque no usas esa libreria para la conexion?

Comment: la use en un principio para conectarlo y funcionaba igual que en este caso pero daba el mismo error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema no guarda relación con los sockets (que tu programa ni siquiera usa directamente).

El problema está en que `os.system()` "detiene" la ejecución de tu programa principal hasta que el comando que has lanzado haya finalizado. En tu caso hasta que `telnet` termine.

Básicamente `os.system()` internamente hace un *fork* para crear un nuevo proceso en el que ejecutar el comando, y ejecuta un *shell* dentro de ese nuevo proceso pasándole como argumento el programa a ejecutar. El proceso principal que hizo *fork* queda a la espera (mediante un *wait()*) de que el proceso hijo finalice.

Esto causará problemas con Tkinter o con cualquier otra GUI, puesto que el proceso principal no debería quedar nunca parado, ya que cuando se para deja de procesar los eventos de la interfaz de usuario. Ya no podrá atender botones pulsados ni otros eventos. De hecho el operativo de vez en cuando le enviará eventos "ping" por así llamar, para verificar que sigue respondiendo a ellos (la respuesta a estos eventos está ya preprogramada en Tkinter como parte del *mainloop*, pero en tu caso este bucle está parado esperando a que acabe `os.system()`). Si el operativo detecta que tu aplicación no responde a los eventos de la GUI durante un tiempo, asumirá que tiene un *bug* y se ha quedado "colgado". En la mayoría de los casos eso termina con que la GUI se cambia a un color más apagado y aparece un mensaje indicando al usuario que "el programa ha dejado de responder", o similar.

Para resolver el problema deberías lanzar tu comando en un subproceso pero sin esperar por él. Esto implica no usar `os.system()`. Cómo hacerlo depende de qué es lo que pretendas, pero en la [documentación del módulo `subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html) tienes algunas ideas y ejemplos.